# Simple Calc user input, i need to break it down to diffrent classes Java eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, class, calculator

So I got a working calc , it got +,-,/,* and it shuts down after asking user if he wanna continue or not , the thing here is im trying to break it down to different classes , so I got a main class Application that just asks user for stuff and classes that got the code for the operators etc
but I really have no idea how to do that I have tried making different classes and putting each one of them in a separate class but didn't work could any of you guys help?

Here is my code ATM

```
package com.example.main;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main{
 public static void main(String[] args) {


boolean status = true;
while (status){

    Scanner minScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Skriv in ditt nummer en och en :\n");
    double nr1 = Double.parseDouble(minScanner.nextLine());
    double nr2 = Double.parseDouble(minScanner.nextLine());

    System.out.println("välj vad du vill göra: ");

    double svar = 0;

    String användarInlägg = minScanner.nextLine();

    if (användarInlägg.equalsIgnoreCase("+"))
    {
        svar = nr1 + nr2;
    } else if (användarInlägg.equalsIgnoreCase("-"))
    {
        svar = nr1 - nr2;
    } else if (användarInlägg.equalsIgnoreCase("*"))
    {
        svar = nr1 * nr2;
    } else if (användarInlägg.equalsIgnoreCase("/")) 
    {
        svar = nr1 / nr2;
    }
    System.out.printf("= %.2f\n ", svar);
    System.out.println("Skriv in J för att fortsätta N för att sluta: \n");


    String input = minScanner.nextLine();

    if (input.equalsIgnoreCase("N"))
        status = false;
    else if (input.equalsIgnoreCase("J")) {
        status = true;
            }
    }

}

}
```

Comment: Please dont be rude im not very good at this just trying to learn if my question is stupid then type why not only a answere like " omg you're stupid"

Comment: You said you tried to put the code in different classes, could you post those classes so we can see what didn't work?

Answer (score 0):

What you have there is a quite primitive calculator because it only supports expressions like `2 3 +`.
If you wan't to evaluate more complicated expressions, there is an [excellent blog post about pratt parsers](http://journal.stuffwithstuff.com/2011/03/19/pratt-parsers-expression-parsing-made-easy/) which already does most of the work. It's really easy to add evaluation to it. This makes for an extensible good structured and robust parser. It's also trivial to add functions, conditions and the ternary operator ?:.

I got it to evaluate expressions like `(2.4 + -5)/(2.4 - -5) * 100/(2.4 * -5)` in just 54 nanoseconds and when compiled to bytecodes (at runtime) just 5 nanoseconds!

Comment: Thanks i looked at it looks good but just trying with simple calc and classes for now :)

Answer (score 0):

```
interface MathOp {
public double doMath(double a, double b);
}

class Add implements MathOp{

  public double doMath(double a, double b) {
    return (a + b);
  }

}

class Sub implements MathOp{

  public double doMath(double a, double b) {
    return (a - b);
  }

}

// do the same for multiplication and divison
```

in the class with the main method

```
class SimpleCalc {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    double a,b,c;
    int choice = 0;
    a=b=c=0.0;
    while(true) {
      System.out.println("Enter two numbers");
      a = Double.parseDouble(sc.nextLine());
      b = Double.parseDouble(sc.nextLine());

      System.out.println("Enter your choice");
      System.out.println("1. Add");
      System.out.println("2. Sub");
      System.out.println("3. Mul");
      System.out.println("4. Div");

      choice = Integer.parseInt(sc.nextLine());

      switch(choice) {
       case 1 :
              c = new Add().mathOp(a,b);
              break;
       case 2 :
              c = new Sub().mathOp(a,b);
              break;
       // do the same for the other classes and use a default case.
       }

      //print the results here and then ask the user's choice

      System.out.println("would you like to continue? (Y/N)");
      if("N".equalsIgnoreCase(sc.nextLine())) { // careful with the paranthesis 
        break;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks alot for the help i made it work with dup and division gonna try to add some other stuff aswell but that  helped me alot thanks for showing this , (bow)

Comment: @user2764700  mark an answer which ever has solved your problem